# Has anyone implemented a wiki in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wiki, wiki-engine

I'm looking for a pure javascript, open-sourced, wiki implementation, preferably one using NodeJS. Where might I find it?

Comment: Yeah, I would also be interested in this. Preferably a PostgreSQL-based one.

Comment: It's currently on the todo list for docpad - https://github.com/balupton/docpad

Comment: Why was this question closed as "not constructive"?

Comment: Anderson: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. In short, it's too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Too bad the question is closed. Tiddlywiki (http://tiddlywiki.com) now has a Node.js version which works quite well!

Comment: Although still in beta, [wiki.js](https://wiki.requarks.io/) looks quite promising...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest [jingo](https://github.com/claudioc/jingo) thanks to its nice design (with very sane typography), use of [git](https://git-scm.com/) as backing datastore, format compatibility with the markdown format used by github ([gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum)), and the fact that it's somewhat actively developed.

As of Jan 2017, [Matterwiki](https://github.com/Matterwiki/Matterwiki) is also actively developed.

[Wiki.js](https://github.com/Requarks/wiki) is also being actively developed. It's using a git datastore, has a markdown editor, search engine and assets management.

[Tiddlywiki can generate static HTML](http://tiddlywiki.com/static/Generating%2520Static%2520Sites%2520with%2520TiddlyWiki.html).

Npmjs and GitHub reveal only two other relatively popular and somewhat active projects: [openKB](https://github.com/mrvautin/openKB) and [Hazel](https://github.com/wkallhof/Hazel).

[Wikipedia shows mostly the same JS wiki engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software#JavaScript-based), plus [Grokla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrokOla_(software)), which is closed source.

Wikimatrix lists [7 wiki engines powered by JavaScript](http://www.wikimatrix.org/search.php?item[51]=JavaScript).

---

Old answer: https://github.com/gjritter/nodewiki (no updates since 2010).

Comment: nodewiki seems out of date; it could use an update to using current libraries and such

Answer (score 9):

[http://nodebits.org/wiki-challenge](https://web.archive.org/web/20120127043634/http://nodebits.org/wiki-challenge)

Uses file system
  https://github.com/nodebits/wiki-challenge

Git based wiki system for markdown files
https://github.com/nhoss2/nodewiki

Git based
https://github.com/claudioc/jingo

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very recent Node.js one: https://github.com/milani/node-gitwiki. Needs work I think.

But if you just want HTML5+CSS+JavaScript, then http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ does without a remote server, all via an in-browser web app. Pretty cool :-)

Comment: node-gitwiki hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: @DanDascalescu ...but tiddlywiki is still going strong and has node.js support, see the node.js tab of http://tiddlywiki.com/#GettingStarted:GettingStarted

Comment: Nice. Maybe time to update your answer?