# Is there a MediaWiki like module for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mediawiki

Is there anything like MediaWiki implemented in node.js, that can be used to create Wikipedia like costumized wikis? Or did somebody do something similar and can give me some advices, on how it should be done?  Becuase I have to make a website for a community that needs wiki functionality, and I thought out the rest for the website, but I couldn't find a proper solution for this problem.

Comment: I flagged this question as too broad, but still, there are some replies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956167/has-anyone-implemented-a-wiki-in-nodejs

Comment: So you need a wiki and you figured out everything except the wiki? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Melkor**, a wiki engine built using node.js

Demo: http://melkor-demo.hiddentao.com
Source: https://github.com/hiddentao/melkor

**Node Wiki**, simple git based wiki system for markdown files written in node.js.

Source: https://github.com/nhoss2/nodewiki

Comment: These will be useful, thanks.